# How to use CSS3 Transition to customize page scrolling

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a way to use CSS3 Transition to create a smooth page scrolling. I know how to do it using javascript but if there's a way to do it with CSS3, i will prefer it for performance purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transform: translate(x,y)` to simulate "scrolling", and this can be animated using transitions via `transition-property: all`;  Note, you will have to add the appropriate vendor prefix, as with much of CSS3 at the moment.

References: [Mozilla Dev Center: transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/transform), [Mozilla Dev Center: CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/css_transitions)

P.S. use percentages carefully with `transform: translate()` -- depending on how your element is wrapped, -100% can mean next 'display-height' section of content

Answer (score 5):

You cannot control the scroll behavior with css. CSS3 transitions enable you to specify the way an element will go from an state to another, scrolling is a browser function not accessible to CSS.