# scroll page slowly on #div

Tags: asp.net, html, css, scroll

I have a page with height 200% of the total viewable area, which means there are approximately two pages one over another. I have to scroll to the bottom to view the other half page. I divided the complete `<body>` into two divs each with a height of **100%**.

In div1, I gave a link like this to the div2, which works,

```
<div id="div1" class="mystyle1">
<a href="#div2">Click Me To Go To DIV2</div>


<div id="div2" class="mystyle2">
<a href="#div1">Click Me To Go To DIV1</div>
```

This works, but it scrolls in an instant, I need it to be smooth so that the user can see the transition. I also tried setting this in CSS:

```
-webkit-transistion: all 1s ease-in-out;
```

No luck!

Comment: are you sure this is achievable with css3 ? And I'm really interested to see the full css you used with transition.

Comment: I this this could be possible using `#div2:target` pseudo-class. No? See I am a beginner, seeking help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657947/how-to-use-css3-transition-to-customize-page-scrolling

Comment: im taking a guess here, but I think you might need to target something else other than the link. as in you might need to manipulate the viewport by running a function when the link is clicked, rather than depending on the default <a> functionality.. psuedocode would be something like, onlcick transition viewport to (x,y)

Comment: Can you suggest some code please?

Comment: I see saveral websites using this functionality, this way they build just one physical page whch contains 5 or more pages, they just scroll between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve conveniently this using Jquery. Googling keywords like [**animated scroll to top**](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/animated-scroll-to-top) and [**animate scroll to ID**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682451/jquery-animate-scroll-to-id-on-page-load) would give you an idea.

Doing a quick fiddle, perhaps this what you want to happen: http://jsfiddle.net/g5D33/

--

By the way, you have some small typos on your code, like `<a>` tag is missing with a closing tag and transition spelled with **s**. ;)

Comment: The fiddle is exactly what I want, but when I copied all that, and tried to run, it is not working. Why?

Comment: Thank you, I used JQuery first time.

Comment: You need to call the Jquery script for it to take effect.

Include this on your `head` tag:
`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: What changes will I have to make this JSFiddle if I want to scroll to left or right?

Comment: You can use `scrollLeft` and negative value for it for right scrolling: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/style-properties/

If you ran into difficulty about it, you can start a new thread, for it is about another issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

For that I always use a small JQuery function

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click( function(){
        var scroll_el = $(this).attr('href');
        if ($(scroll_el).length != 0) { 
                    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(scroll_el).offset().top }, 700); 
        }
        return false;
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hpkttfmp/1/)

For scrolling horisontally:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click( function(){
            var scroll_el = $(this).attr('href');
            if ($(scroll_el).length != 0) { 
                        $('html, body').animate({ scrollLeft: $(scroll_el).offset().left }, 700); 
            }
            return false;
    });
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hpkttfmp/2/)